# ISO-8859-1 Input to UTF-8 Output via VFS

Tags: esb, wso2-esb

We receive a XML file (not well-formed) encoded as ISO-8859-1 on a Linux system. An ESB Proxy picks this up and uses a Sequence to forward with SAMBA VFS to a Windows share.

On Windows certain characters are not displayed properly because I can't get it to encode as UTF-8. I have tried several approaches all without success. Using xxd these are the characters I have problems with:

```
0000b70: 4c55 45ef bfbd 5344 204a 503c 2f69 7373  LUEï.½SD JP</iss
0000bf0: 5445 4749 4320 5641 4c55 45ef bfbd 5344  TEGIC VALUEï.½SD
```

The half symbol. The proxy is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Proxy" transports="vfs" statistics="enable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
  <target faultSequence="ErrorSequence">
    <inSequence>
       <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
       <clone sequential="true">
         <target sequence="Sequence"/>
       </clone>
    </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">60</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///data/process</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///data/incoming</parameter>  
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///data/failed</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">security.*</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain; charset="UTF-8"</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
  <description/>
</proxy>
```

The sequence is:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Sequence" onError="ErrorSequence" trace="enable">
  <xslt key="UTF8Convert">
    <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    <property name="messageType" value="text/xml"></property>
    <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml; charset=UTF-8</property>
  </xslt>
  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="filename" expression="(get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME'))"></property>
  <property name="transport.vfs.ContentType" value="text/xml; charset=&quot;UTF-8&quot;" scope="transport" type="STRING"></property
  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="get-property('filename')" scope="transport"></property>
  <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"></property>
  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="serverurl" expression="fn:concat('vfs:smb://',fn:normalize-space(get-property('DOMAIN')),'\',fn:normalize-space(get-property('USERNAME')),':',fn:normalize-space(get-property('PWD')),'@',fn:normalize-space(get-property('DESTINATION')),'/',fn:normalize-space(get-property('DIR')),'/')"></property>
  <header xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="To" expression="fn:concat(get-property('serverurl'),get-property('filename'))"></header>
  <send>
    <endpoint>
      <default></default>
    </endpoint>
  </send>
</sequence>
```

The XSLT is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The trace log is like this:

```
00:35:09,924 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Sequence<ApexXMLToEPMSequence>
00:35:09,924 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting the onError handler : ErrorSequence for the sequence : Sequence
00:35:09,924 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Sequence <SequenceMediator> ::mediate()
00:35:09,925 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Mediation started from mediator position : 0
00:35:09,925 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : XSLT mediator
00:35:09,927 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting parameter 'encoding' to 'UTF-8'
00:35:09,927 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting parameter 'messageType' to 'text/xml'
00:35:09,927 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting parameter 'ContentType' to 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'
00:35:09,927 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER output method: xml; encoding: UTF-8
00:35:09,927 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Using org.apache.synapse.util.jaxp.StreamSourceBuilder
00:35:09,932 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Transformation completed - processing result
00:35:09,933 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Replace node with result
00:35:09,933 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : XSLT mediator
00:35:09,933 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
00:35:09,933 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : filename at scope : default to : security.2016046.113132 (i.e. result of expression : (get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME')))
00:35:09,933 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
00:35:09,933 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
00:35:09,933 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : transport.vfs.ContentType at scope : transport to : text/xml; charset="UTF-8" (i.e. constant : text/xml; charset="UTF-8")
00:35:09,933 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
00:35:09,933 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : transport.vfs.ReplyFileName at scope : transport to : security.2016046 (i.e. result of expression : get-property('filename'))
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : OUT_ONLY at scope : default to : true (i.e. constant : true)
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Property mediator
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Setting property : serverurl at scope : default to : vfs:smb://AC\user:passw@eserver/folder/ (i.e. result of expression : fn:concat('vfs:smb://',fn:normalize-space(get-property('DOMAIN')),'\',fn:normalize-space(get-property('USERNAME')),':',fn:normalize-space(get-property('PWD')),'@',fn:normalize-space(get-property('DESTINATION')),'/', fn:normalize-space(get-property('DIR')),'/'))
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Property mediator
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Header mediator
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Set SOAP header : To to : vfs:smb://AC\user:passw@server/folder/security.2016046
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Header mediator
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Start : Send mediator
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER Sending message through endpoint : null resolving to address = vfs:smb://AC\user:passw@server/folder/security.2016046
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER SOAPAction: urn:mediate
00:35:09,934 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER WSA-Action: urn:mediate
00:35:09,935 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Send mediator
00:35:09,935 [-] [vfs-Worker-18]  INFO TRACE_LOGGER End : Sequence <Sequence>
```

The output on Windows shows as the input above with no coding to UTF-8. How do I make the ESB re-encode please?

Answer (score 0):

If your xml file is encoded as ISO-8859-1, why do you configure your VFS proxy to read it as UTF-8 with : `<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain; charset="UTF-8"</parameter>` ?

It seems that you read it as UTF-8 and write it as UTF-8

If you want to force output encoding with VFS, try to set a property named "CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING" before send

Answer (score 0):

If you try to decode ISO-8859-1 encoded files using UTF-8, you will end up with some symbolic character representations (like accented characters). So best thing is Send the file as it is.

Use the VFS parameter like below,

```
 <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1</parameter>
```

Add the following property and try your scenario.

```
 <property name="messageType" value="text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" scope="axis2"/>
```